# Does force.start (d3.js) work in the background?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, force-layout

How does `force.start()`of the force layout work? Are the positions of the nodes updated by a background process (started by Start) or do I have to do it myself?

Answer (score 1):

Though the docs aren't that clear, calling `start` is enough to get the simulation started.

[`force.start()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Force-Layout#wiki-start) ([source](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/master/src/layout/force.js#L189)) sets up the internal state of the layout based on the nodes and links that you have defined.  Confusingly, you need to also call `start` *any time* you change your nodes or links.

Under the covers, `force.start()` calls `force.resume()` which calls into `force.alpha()` which starts a run loop on your behalf (repeatedly calling `force.tick()` to advance the simulation)

Answer (score -1):

Have you read the [documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Force-Layout#wiki-start)? It reads to me as though it happens automatically - so you shouldn't have to worry about it.

Have you actually tried this? Generally SO questions should be regarding specific problems that you have, and should generally contain code.

Comment: Yes but it's not clear on what it does. I also reviewed the code, suggested by Nevir and it's clear now.